# Create a digital signature in a file to prevent tampering with the file in C#

Tags: c#, security, licensing, digital-signature

I am trying to create a simple licensing verification for a software and I want verify is a file has been modified. I have XML file with license information and date when the license expires.

If someone changes this file - How do I detect?

Has to be difficult to change the application (C# .NET) if someone changes the file and hack the application (to skip the verification - I have to stop that too)

ClickOnce does that... You cannot modify the contents of a clickonce manifest, yet it is readable XML format file. I want the same

Comment: Asked millions of times. You can not stop someone with enough patience.

Comment: You could encrypt the file contents, but somebody with enough determination can modify your software no matter how hard you try to protect it.

Comment: To Eser: It does not have to be perfect... It has to make it as difficult as possible

Comment: To Ron Beyer: I don't want to encrypt. I want the file to be readable. I just want to know if someone modified it or if it still have the original contents. ClickOnce does that... You cannot modify the contents of a clickonce manifest, yet it is readable XML format file. I want the same

Comment: You can build a hashcode on the files you want to check for change and store that in your xml files. But like all cracked software, if a pirate is going to go as far as change the software, they're just simply going to bypass the hash code check or anything you're doing to protect it.  Your best bet is to invest in a 3rd party license server solution to control "casual" piracy.

Comment: Why would you want to keep the file readable? Encrypt the file and decrypt it when the app starts.

Comment: Another strategy, if you can insist the application is always connected online, is to put critical APIs the application uses on your server.  That way licensing is controlled via user account, and far easier to revoke when you need to.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  This is a reasonable question that is addressed in the [XML Signature Syntax and Processing](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-EnvelopedSignature) W3C recommendation, notably § 6.6.4 for enveloped signatures.  The ClickOnce manifest referred to in the question uses this standard.

Comment: .NET also includes APIs for adding signatures to XML documents and verifying the signatures.  Refer to [How to: Sign XML Documents with Digital Signatures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745(v=vs.110).aspx) and [How to: Verify the Digital Signatures of XML Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229950(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN for examples.